# Why can't my app be published using paypal integration

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, app-store

I developed an app with ionic library and use paypal integration from ionic framework. I uploaded my app at google play and everything went fine. When I published my app in app store my app was rejected with this reason :

> We noticed that your app or its metadata enables the purchase of
>   content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the
>   in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

Does anyone know if the problem is that I use paypal library or that apple doesn't control my transactions so apple can't take some money?

Comment: if your app sells digital goods from within the app you have to use In App Purchase APIs (plug-in) and yes there is rev share that comes with it

Answer (score 0):

Other methods are allowed, but only under certain conditions:

> 3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

You can read all the app story review guidelines at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

Comment: i understand what u mean, so the point is i cant use paypal integration. so ionic too should not says that paypal integration supported by ios :https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal

Comment: All depends on what you're selling.

Comment: i unlock items in my app. so the user can see 3 items for free in begin, then he click on button and be asked if he wants to buyt 3 more items for 1,5 euros. if he click yes then he must pay with paypal integration api (in the app).

Comment: You can only use in-app Purchases if you unlock content. Apple wants their cut of 30% - 40%. I did see https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase for implementation.

Comment: is that in-app purchase works? cause i have install it in my app but i cant use it, always products list is empty